# .replace in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using .replace method to replace `onclick` function on anchor tag but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var htm= $('.jitu').html();
htm.replace("show()",'showme()');
})
</script>

<div class="jitu"><a href="#" onclick="show()">me</a> </div>
```

Comment: Why is the `onclick` there in the first place if you want to replace it immediately? Why are you using `onclick` instead of `.bind()` or `.on()`?

Comment: you mean [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use :-

```
$('.jitu a').attr('onclick','showme()');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fxfvn/

Explanation on your code:-
What you are doing is just replacing a string not the real DOM. ALso this is not an ideal way to change an attribute. here html is just an html string and no reference...

```
var htm= $('.jitu').html();
htm.replace("show()",'showme()');
```

Since you are using jquery. You can directly bind

```
$('.jitu a').removeAttr('onclick').click(showme); //(if you have onclick. to avoid duplicate alert)
```

else

```
$('.jitu a').click(showme);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.attr( attributeName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
$('.jitu').find('[onclick="show()"]').attr('onclick', 'showme()');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CfpBP/

However you should consider using more unobtrusive way to bind events. For example:

```
$('.jitu a').click(showme);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just doing a string replacement doesn't do anything if you're not applying the final value to the element; this would work but I would not recommend it:

```
var $jitu = $('.jitu');
$jitu.html($jitu.html().replace('show()', 'showme()'));
```

The more correct way is to unhook the old `onclick` and replace it with a new click handler:

```
$('.jitu > a')
    .prop('onclick', null)
    .on('click', showme);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/aquziy/1/)

It would be even better if you didn't even have the inline `onclick="show()"` in the first place and just use `$(element).on(event, fn)` to register your click handlers.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
htm.onclick = function() { showme(); };
```